# Optim error training ARIMA model in R

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting, arima

I have the code below which trains ARIMA models for a range of order combinations. I'm getting the error below in the step training the ARIMA models.  The code worked just fine with the `hsales` time-series provided for Hyndman's text book in the "fpp" package in R. If anyone can point out the issue or suggest how to solve it, I would be grateful.

Code:

```
library("forecast")
library("tseries")
library("sqldf")
library("manipulate")
library("dplyr")
library("xts")

tsTrain <- tsTrain
tsTest <- tsValidation

pvar<-1:17
dvar<-1:2
qvar<-1:17

##Creating All Combingations

OrderGrid<-expand.grid(pvar,dvar,qvar)

##Vectorize Suggestion

n <- function(a,b,c) {Arima(tsTrain, order=c(a,b,c),method="ML")}
mod_fit <- do.call(Vectorize(n, SIMPLIFY=FALSE), unname(OrderGrid))
```

Error:

```
Error in optim(init[mask], armafn, method = optim.method, hessian = TRUE,  : 
  non-finite finite-difference value [3]
```

Data:

```
c(11, 14, 17, 5, 5, 5.5, 8, NA, 5.5, 6.5, 8.5, 4, 5, 9, 10, 11, 
7, 6, 7, 7, 5, 6, 9, 9, 6.5, 9, 3.5, 2, 15, 2.5, 17, 5, 5.5, 
7, 6, 3.5, 6, 9.5, 5, 7, 4, 5, 4, 9.5, 3.5, 5, 4, 4, 9, 4.5, 
6, 10, NA, 9.5, 15, 9, 5.5, 7.5, 12, 17.5, 19, 7, 14, 17, 3.5, 
6, 15, 11, 10.5, 11, 13, 9.5, 9, 7, 4, 6, 15, 5, 18, 5, 6, 19, 
19, 6, 7, 7.5, 7.5, 7, 6.5, 9, 10, 5.5, 5, 7.5, 5, 4, 10, 7, 
5, 12, 6, NA, 4, 2, 5, 7.5, 11, 13, 7, 8, 7.5, 5.5, 7.5, 15, 
7, 4.5, 9, 3, 4, 6, 17.5, 11, 7, 6, 7, 4.5, 4, 4, 5, 10, 14, 
7, 7, 4, 7.5, 11, 6, 11, 7.5, 15, 23.5, 8, 12, 5, 9, 10, 4, 9, 
6, 8.5, 7.5, 6, 5, 8, 6, 5.5, 8, 11, 10.5, 4, 6, 7, 10, 11.5, 
11.5, 3, 4, 16, 3, 2, 2, 8, 4.5, 7, 4, 8, 11, 6.5, 7.5, 17, 6, 
6.5, 9, 12, 17, 10, 5, 5, 9, 3, 8.5, 11, 4.5, 7, 16, 11, 14, 
6.5, 15, 8.5, 7, 6.5, 11, 2, 2, 13.5, 4, 2, 16, 11.5, 3.5, 9, 
16.5, 2.5, 4.5, 8.5, 5, 6, 7.5, 9.5, NA, 9.5, 8, 2.5, 4, 12, 
13, 10, 4, 6, 16, 16, 13, 8, 12, 19, 19, 5.5, 8, 6.5, NA, NA, 
NA, 15, 12, NA, 6, 11, 8, 4, 2, 3, 4, 10, 7, 5, 4.5, 4, 5, 11.5, 
12, 10.5, 4.5, 3, 4, 7, 15.5, 9.5, NA, 9.5, 12, 13.5, 10, 10, 
13, 6, 8.5, 15, 16.5, 9.5, 14, 9, 9.5, 11, 15, 14, 5.5, 6, 14, 
16, 9.5, 23, NA, 19, 12, 5, 11, 16, 8, 11, 9, 13, 6, 7, 3, 5.5, 
7.5, 19, 6.5, 5.5, 4.5, 7, 8, 7, 10, 11, 13, NA, 12, 1.5, 7, 
7, 12, 8, 6, 9, 15, 9, 3, 5, 11, 11, 8, 6, 3, 7.5, 4, 7, 7.5, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 6.5, 2, 16.5, 7.5, 8, 8, 5, 2, 7, 4, 6.5, 4.5, 
10, 6, 4.5, 6.5, 9, 2, 6, 3.5, NA, 5, 7, 3.5, 4, 4.5, 13, 19, 
8.5, 10, 8, 13, 10, 10, 6, 13.5, 12, 11, 5.5, 6, 3.5, 9, 8, NA, 
6, 5, 8.5, 3, 12, 10, 9.5, 7, 24, 7, 9, 11.5, 5, 7, 11, 6, 5.5, 
3, 4.5, 4, 5, 5, 3, 4.5, 6, 10, 5, 4, 4, 9.5, 5, 7, 6, 3, 13, 
5.5, 5, 7.5, 3, 5, 6.5, 5, 5.5, 6, 4, 3, 5, NA, 5, 5, 6, 7, 8, 
5, 5.5, 9, 6, 8.5, 9.5, 8, 9, 6, 12, 5, 7, 5, 3.5, 4, 7.5, 7, 
5, 4, 4, NA, 7, 5.5, 6, 8.5, 6.5, 9, 3, 2, 8, 15, 6, 4, 10, 7, 
13, 14, 9.5, 9, 18, 6, 5, 4, 6, 4, 11.5, 17.5, 7, 8, 10, 4, 7, 
5, 9, 6, 5, 4, 8, 4, 2, 1.5, 3.5, 6, 5.5, 5, 4, 8, 10.5, 4, 11, 
9.5, 5, 6, 11, 21, 9.5, 11, 13.5, 7.5, 13, 10, 7, 9.5, 6, 10, 
5.5, 6.5, 12, 10, 10, 6.5, 2, 8, NA, 10, 5, 4, 4.5, 5, 7.5, 12, 
22, 5, 8.5)
```

Comment: @javlacalle: the post you link to is completely different. Did you paste in the wrong link?

Comment: @StephanKolassa that's the post I wanted to link. Maybe it's not a duplicate, but I see many resemblances in the code; also, the error that is returned is the same and most likely due to the same reason (model not sensible for the data).

Comment: @StephanKolassa  Hi the code was used from the other post, and applied to a different dataset.  It's getting the same optim error as the other post, but the solution from the other post was to set the method="ML".  Setting the method="ML" isn't solving the error for the current data.

Comment: @StephanKolassa I'm also getting errors when trying method="CSS" and method="CSS-ML", would increasing the train set length or shrinking the range of p,d,q values help?  Do I need to specify a value for init and if so do you have a suggestion how to pick one?